# Include shortcode as div content in php code

Tags: php, html, embed, shortcode

Just need to get this shortcode included within this PHP working correctly. I need to include it in the last div 'Loc_Pic64'.....  ....have tried using `echo do_shortcode` but have not had any luck

[google-map-v3 shortcodeid="TO_BE_GENERATED" width="124" height="124" zoom="12" maptype="roadmap" mapalign="center" directionhint="false" language="default" poweredby="false" maptypecontrol="true" pancontrol="true" zoomcontrol="true" scalecontrol="true" streetviewcontrol="false" scrollwheelcontrol="false" draggable="true" tiltfourtyfive="false" enablegeolocationmarker="false" enablemarkerclustering="false" addmarkermashup="false" addmarkermashupbubble="false" bubbleautopan="true" distanceunits="km" showbike="false" showtraffic="false" showpanoramio="false"]

```
<?php
echo " <div id='loc_con'>
<div id='Loc_Pic64'></div>
<div id='Loc_Content'>
<div id='Loc_Name'><b><a href='" . $Loc_Web . "'>" . $Loc_Name . "</a></b></div>
<div id='Loc_Add'><b> $Loc_Add </b></div>
<div id='Loc_Phone'><b> $Loc_Phone </b></div>
<div id='Loc_Hours'><b> $Loc_Hours </b></div>
<div id='Loc_Description'>  $Description </div>
</div>
<div id='Loc_Pic64'></div>
<div id='Loc_Pic64'>

</div>
</div>";}
?>
```

Comment: Can you post your tried code with `do_shortcode` ?

Comment: Just add "echo do_shortcode(["shortcode"]);" in the gap above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
echo " <div id='loc_con'>
<div id='Loc_Pic64'></div>
<div id='Loc_Content'>
<div id='Loc_Name'><b><a href='" . $Loc_Web . "'>" . $Loc_Name . "</a></b></div>
<div id='Loc_Add'><b> $Loc_Add </b></div>
<div id='Loc_Phone'><b> $Loc_Phone </b></div>
<div id='Loc_Hours'><b> $Loc_Hours </b></div>
<div id='Loc_Description'>  $Description </div>
</div>
<div id='Loc_Pic64'></div>
<div id='Loc_Pic64'>".
do_shortcode(["shortcode"])
."</div>
</div>";
```

Comment: Found it out; add $map_display = do_shortcode("[shortcode]"); before the echo command, then just add $map_display between the div tags.

Comment: I just updated, it was semi-colon which causing the issue. The update answer will work too.